# assign a reserved word of sql as a variable in a sql query

Tags: sql, django

I would like to know how to put a reserved word of sql as a variable in a sql query (I use postgresql)

```
def requeteDB(sql_request):
    with connection.cursor() as cursor:
        cursor.execute(*sql_request)
        row = cursor.fetchall()
    return row

def query1(choice, limit):
    return('''
           SELECT col1, SUM(col2) as nb
           FROM Table
           GROUP BY col1
           ORDER BY nb %s
           LIMIT %s
           ''', [choice, limit])

requeteDB(query1(choice="DESC", limit="5"))
> *** django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: ERROR: Type 'nb' does not exist
LINE 10: ORDER BY nb 'DESC'
------------------^
```

Comment: What database do you use?

Comment: @Willem Van Onsem hello i use postgresql

Answer (score -1):

Likely the reason this fails is because of the second `AS`, so you can fix this with:

```
def query1(choice, limit):
    return (
        '''
           SELECT col1, SUM(col2) as nb
           ORDER BY nb %s
           LIMIT %s
           ''',
        [choice, limit],
    )
```

In case you *do* use a reserved keyword, you can *escape* the variable name. For [postgresql](/questions/tagged/postgresql), this is with double quotes, so:

```
def query1(choice, limit):
    return (
        '''
           SELECT col1, SUM(col2) as "nb"
           ORDER BY "nb" %s
           LIMIT %s
           ''',
        [choice, limit],
    )
```

Comment: Hello, i removed the second *as*. When i add quote on nb, i still have the same problem

Comment: @problème0123: please edit the question, and include the *full* error.

Comment: @problème0123: but you still have an `as nb as`, whereas the second `as` should be removed...

Comment: I did the editing, and i forgot the *GROUP BY col1*.