# put a word with white space as a variable in a sql query using .format()

Tags: django, postgresql

I would like to know how to put a word with white space as a variable in a sql query (I use postgresql)

```
data   = "something with white space"
choice = "DESC"
limit  = 10 

def rDB(sql_request):
    with connection.cursor() as cursor:
        cursor.execute(sql_request)
        row = cursor.fetchall()
    return row

queryWithFormat(data, choice, limit):
    return('''
           SELECT col1, SUM(col2) as nb
           FROM Table
           WHERE col1 = {d}
           GROUP BY col1 
           ORDER BY nb {c}
           LIMIT {l}
           '''.format(d=data, c=choice, l=limit)

rDB(queryWithFormat(data, choice, limit))

django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: ERROR: syntax error on or near 'with'
LINE 8: WHERE col1 = something with white ...
-------------------------------^
```

---

Possible solution but I don't know if it's a good practice

- unpack sql request
- i use format() for "DESC"/"ASC"
- and %s for word with white space

fdsfe

```
def requeteDB(sql_request):
    with connection.cursor() as cursor:
        cursor.execute(*sql_request)
        row = cursor.fetchall()
    return row

queryWithFormat(data, choice, limit):
    return('''
           SELECT col1, SUM(col2) as nb
           FROM Table
           WHERE col1 = %s
           GROUP BY col1 
           ORDER BY nb {0}
           LIMIT %s
           '''.format(choice), [data,limit])
```

Comment: Not a Django-programmer myself, but this looks like SQL injection... Did you check this article? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/db/sql/

Comment: @Frank Heikens hello yes i read this article. I have a problem using **%s**, I posted my problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74840312/assign-a-reserved-word-of-sql-as-a-variable-in-a-sql-query). While waiting to find a solution I wanted to explore .format() but I also had a problem ^^

Comment: By the way, your SQL isn't valid either, you use an aggregation without creating the group. GROUP BY col1 would solve this.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to not use Python's native string formatting at all! Instead, you should create a parameterised query.

It would be possible to make your code work, I think, by quoting the variable `col1 = '{d}'`, but I am telling you this for information only and **you should not do it**. It is a security risk. For best practice, [see this section of the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/db/sql/#passing-parameters-into-raw).

Django aside (not my area of expertise...), it looks like you're using SQLAlchemy to execute the query. This library has [its own syntax and methods for parameter binding](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/tutorial.html#using-textual-sql), which you could implement as follows:

```py
from sqlalchemy.sql import text

def query_with_format(data, choice, limit):
    query = text("""
           SELECT col1, SUM(col2) as nb
             FROM Table
            WHERE col1 = :d
         GROUP BY col1
         ORDER BY nb :c
            LIMIT :l
    """)
    query.bindparams(d=data, c=choice, l=limit)
    return query

rDB(query_with_format(data, choice, limit))
```

I do not think you will have any trouble with variables containing whitespace with this approach, and it is far, far safer.

Comment: Hello, i get a error; **TypeError: Boolean value of this clause is not defined**

Comment: Was this before or after you fixed the GROUP BY (edited into my suggestion now)? Also, your `data` parameter doesn't contain the words 'and' or 'or' by any chance, does it?

Comment: After fixed the *group by*, in *data* there is no *and* or *or*. I make another query with only `Select ... From ... Where colX = :d` , I have the same error (*:d* contain a str with only number). I think the problem come from **=**.

Comment: Wait, `:d` corresponds to a string containing only a number, e.g. `"3"`? I don't think you mentioned that before.

Comment: hello, it's my second test, in my first test it's a word with white space.

Comment: I just realized can't we use both method *format()* and *%s*. With *format()* I could put in variable DESC and with %s put a word with a white space. I did different test which all work. But I don't know if it's a good practice. I edited my post to add the solution anyway.

Comment: If you're using string formatting rather than proper query parameterisation then [you'd better be 100% sure the choice of inputs will never given to a third party/end user](https://bobby-tables.com/).

Comment: On reflection, I wrote my answer too hastily. It may not be possible to parameterise a SQL _keyword_ like 'ASC' vs 'DESC', which I now notice is what you're doing. In that case you may need to format that part of the string. My previous comment still stands: your application code will have to limit the set of values that can be used to just those two, not allow free choice of that value.